# If the function $g$ is concave, what can I say about monotonicity of $(g(x+c)-g(x))e^{\lambda(g(x+c)-g(x))}$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, optimization, convex-analysis

Let $\lambda > 0$,

if the function $g$ is concave, what can I say about monotonicity of the function $$x \mapsto(g(x+c)-g(x))(e^{\lambda(g(x+c)-g(x))}-1),$$

where $c$ is some constant.

My guess is that it would be monotone decreasing, but I am having trouble justifying it.

My attempt: by concavity of $g$ we have,

$g(x+c)\leq g(x) +\alpha_{x} c$ for some $\alpha_{x}$ that is a subgradient of $g$ at $x$, and let $y > x$ with corresponding $\alpha_{y}$.Essentially, I just want to prove that: $g(y+c)-g(y)\leq g(x+c)-g(x)$ because this would immediately imply that $$x \mapsto(g(x+c)-g(x))(e^{\lambda(g(x+c)-g(x))}-1)$$ is monotone decreasing.

$g(y+c)-g(y)\leq \alpha_{y} c \leq \alpha_{x}c $ since $x \mapsto \alpha_{x}$ is monotone decreasing by concavity (we assume the map is well-defined by choosing only the left-derivative as $\alpha_{x}$).

But I cannot bound $a_{x}c\leq g(x+c)-g(x)$, so I do not know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am assuming that $c > 0$, but a similar argument would also work for $c < 0$).

Using your notation of $a_x$ for the subgradient we have for $x < y < x+c$:
$$
 g(y+c)-g(x+c) \le a_{x+c}(y-x) \le a_y(y-x) \le g(y)-g(x)
$$
since the subgradient of a convex function is decreasing. It follows that
$$
 h(x) = g(x+c)- g(x)
$$
is a decreasing function.

The function $F(u) = u(e^{\lambda u} -1)$ is decreasing on $(-\infty, 0]$, and increasing on $[0, \infty)$. Therefore we can conclude:

- If $g$ is concave and increasing then $h$ is decreasing and non-negative, so that $F \circ h$ is decreasing.
- If $g$ is concave and decreasing then $h$ is decreasing and non-positive, so that $F \circ h$ is increasing.